# Creating Zip Archive in memory, and returning it from a web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, memorystream

So i am trying to create a zip archive and return it from my web api. The controller is called from an angular 2 site. Currently the zip file is created but when i open it i get an invalid message. Originally i had the streams in using statements but had to change that as they were being disposed before the request had completed.

What i need is to create the zip file, add the csv file to its content. And then return the zip file. But the zip file is always invalid. I have read the zip archive needs to be disposed in order for it write its contents, however im not sure what is the best way to implement this. Thank you for any guidance.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExportReport(int id, ReportModel report)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await ReportGenerationService.ExportReportForId(id, report.Page, report.PageSize, report.SortField, report.SortDir, report.SearchTerm, report.StartDate, report.EndDate, report.UserId, report.TeamId, report.SelectedDateItem);
            if (result != null)
            {

                var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();

                var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false);

                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("textExport.csv");
                var origionalFileSteam = new MemoryStream(result.ExportToBytes());
                var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open();
                origionalFileSteam.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);


                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StreamContent(compressedFileStream)};
                response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "Export.zip"
                };

                var t = compressedFileStream.CanRead;
                return ResponseMessage(response);

            }

            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

In Response to using statements:

At one point i had everything wrapped in using statements but the response would fail because the stream had already been disposed. You can see this below.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExportReport(int id, ReportModel report)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await ReportGenerationService.ExportReportForId(id, report.Page, report.PageSize, report.SortField, report.SortDir, report.SearchTerm, report.StartDate, report.EndDate, report.UserId, report.TeamId, report.SelectedDateItem);
            if (result != null)
            {

                var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();
                var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false);

                        //Create a zip entry for each attachment
                    var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("textExport.csv");

                    //Get the stream of the attachment
                    using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(result.ExportToBytes()))
                    using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                        //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
                    }
                    compressedFileStream.Position = 0;

                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StreamContent(compressedFileStream)};
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                    {
                        FileName = "Export.zip"
                    };

                    return ResponseMessage(response);
            }

            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you use a browser to call the web-api method, and save the result to file?  And see if it is a legit or illegit file....aka, take angular out of the equation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a handful of `using(){}` blocks.

Make sure you close the originalFileSteam, zipEntryStream and the zipArchive in the proper order.

And just to be sure, reset the memoryStream. I don't know if this is needed but it won't hurt.

```
//using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(...)) 
{
        //Create a zip entry for each attachment
        var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("textExport.csv");

        //Get the stream of the attachment
        using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(result.ExportToBytes()))
        using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) 
        {
            //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
            originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
        }
}

//compressedFileStream .Position = 0;
var responseBytes =new MemoryStream(compressedFileStream.ToArray());

var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {Content = new StreamContent(responseBytes )};
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return ResponseMessage(response);
```

Comment: I have added the using statements to the question. I tried it previously but get more errors because the stream is already disposed when we send the reponse.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention the memStream. It should stay open or be reopened. And the other usings should close _before_ sending the response.

Comment: I edited and I left the indentation a little bit in a mess so you can see where you went wrong.  Close the zipArchive before the sendoff.

Comment: A i see i had the response within the using statement for the zip archive. Only issue here is that the compressedFileStream is closed when we try to set the position.

Comment: When zipArchive closes it (??, are you sure you don't?) then reopen a new stream from the old buffer. MemStream.Buffer stays accessible.

Comment: did you see the top 2 lines here, about compressedFileStream ?

Comment: Yer ive got them in, the zip file returns but is still invalid

Comment: Yes, the Archive does close the stream. I have edited a little. ToArray() has the correct length, forget the buffer.

Comment: Got it working now, thank you for your help on this, your changes in combination with the other answer of leaving the ZipArchive open worked great.

Comment: Yes, I had forgotten about LeaveOpen. Much cleaner than building a new stream.

Comment: Yes building the new stream means you will be using a lot more memory as you copy the data over

Comment: @Nkosi - not when you can reuse the Buffer. But with ToArray(), yes.

Comment: @bommelding I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Nkosi - the horrible indentation is there for a reason.

Comment: @bommelding my bad. OCD took over.

Answer (score 7):

The memory stream is being disposed when the zip archive is disposed.

You should dispose of the archive to force it to write its content to its underlying memory stream, but take note of the following

> #### [ZipArchive.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158289(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)
>
> Unless you construct the object by using the [`ZipArchive(Stream, ZipArchiveMode, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137431(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor overload and set its `leaveOpen` parameter to `true`, all underlying streams are closed and no longer available for subsequent write operations.
>
> When you are finished using this instance of `ZipArchive`, call `Dispose()` to release all resources used by this instance. You should eliminate further references to this `ZipArchive` instance so that the garbage collector can reclaim the memory of the instance instead of keeping it alive for finalization.

And since you want to continue using the memory stream then you need to make sure it remains open and that the stream pointer is reset so that is can be read from the beginning.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ExportReport(int id, ReportModel report) {
    try {
        var result = await ReportGenerationService.ExportReportForId(id, report.Page, report.PageSize, report.SortField, report.SortDir, report.SearchTerm, report.StartDate, report.EndDate, report.UserId, report.TeamId, report.SelectedDateItem);
        if (result != null) {
            var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream();
            using(var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, 
                leaveOpen: true)) { //<--This is important to keep stream open
                //Create a zip entry for each attachment
                var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("textExport.csv");
                //Get the stream of the attachment
                using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(result.ExportToBytes()))
                using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open()) {
                    //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                    await originalFileStream.CopyToAsync(zipEntryStream);
                }
            }// disposal of archive will force data to be written/flushed to memory stream.
            compressedFileStream.Position = 0;//reset memory stream position.
            
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                Content = new StreamContent(compressedFileStream)
            };
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
                FileName = "Export.zip"
            };
            return ResponseMessage(response);
        }
        return NotFound();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this, id like to mark both answers as correct ideally. Leaving the ziparchive open helped a lot. Again thank you.

Comment: @Tony_89 no worries. The other answer is very valuable and got you most of the way there.